# How to know the length of message from the entropy

Tags: computer-science, information-theory

I have a message from four symbols and each symbol has a different probability.

For example: a message is built by symbols A, B, C, D, and the probabilities of there occurrences are x,y,z,t.

The question is, how can I calculate or know the required number of these symbols, which makes the entropy of message equal to or bigger than N bits for example 200 bits?

I know that I have to use Shannon's formula, but how?

Comment: do you know the formula?

Comment: Yes, but to how can I apply I here, we are using this formula to calculate the entropy of (i) letters, now I have the entropy and I have to find (i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find what you need at:

http://bearcave.com/misl/misl_tech/wavelets/compression/shannon.html

Your average bits per symbol is:

$H = -[x \log_2{x} + y \log_2{y} + z \log_2{z} + t \log_2{t}]$

And the number you're looking for is N/H (on average)

Comment: Question please, how can I calculate the information amount or the entropy of a text string, I mean, if I have a sentence "this is a string", the entropy will be calculate by Shannon's formula (probability of each symbol by table of english language symbols entropy) or just the entropy of English log2(26) × the length of the sentence?

Comment: @Mohaboko : the link in the answer explains it for a short string $AAAAABBCDE$ by taking the percentage of occurrences of each letter ($A$ has 0.5 and so on). This string has $H=1.9$ bits.

Comment: I found the required number of symbols, but it's with float point, 63.73837, I have to round up it for 64 symbols, right?